# Select Layer Attribute Management -SQL Query

Tags: python, arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am trying to make a layer from schools that depicts schools at greater than 700 meters. There is an attribute field "ELEV_METER" that has the numeric value for elevation. The query keeps being rejected. I can do this in ArcMAP but need the python script to work. Any ideas?

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


schools = "Schools"
highelevschools = "HighElevSchools"


arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(schools, highelevschools)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(highelevschools, "NEW_SELECTION", "ELEV_METER" >= 700)
```

Comment: is there an error being produced or just an empty output?

Comment: What do you mean by "query keeps being rejected"?  Does the code you present lead to that and/or an error message or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a SQL query in MakeFeatureLayer so you dont need to use SelectLayerByAttribute (unless you want to, in that case the same SQL query below should work). Try using [AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) and [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import arcpy

schools=r'C:\TEST.gdb\schools'

sql="""{0} >=700""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(schools, "ELEV_METER"))
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=schools, out_layer='highelevschools', where_clause=sql)
```